# Cuda-Fortran MPI_Sendrecv segmentation fault

Tags: cuda, fortran

I am trying to run the code in "Cuda-Fortran for scientists and engineer"
But runing in a segment fault I do not understand.

```
[mpi_rank_0][error_sighandler] Caught error: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
[mpi_rank_1][error_sighandler] Caught error: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
[mpi_rank_2][error_sighandler] Caught error: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
[mpi_rank_3][error_sighandler] Caught error: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
```

My system is a 64 linux and I do have PGI compilers. The cuda driver is 4.0 following is the code as I took it from the book. I could compile but it seems the MPI_Sendrecv does not work. 
I have MVAPICH2.1.8 installed. 
The code was copiled this the command

```
/usr/.../mvapich/bin/mpif90 filename.cuf
```

**Edited based on your comments**

When I builds with the -C option, the compiling fails

```
pgfortran-Info-Switch -Mvect -fast forces -O2
PGF90-S-0155-Kernel region ignored; see -Minfo messages  (transposeMVA.cuf: 188)
transposempi:
    140, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
    146, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
    157, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
    190, Accelerator restriction: function/procedure calls are not supported
         Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
    191, Accelerator restriction: function/procedure calls are not supported
    217, all reduction inlined
         Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
  0 inform,   0 warnings,   1 severes, 0 fatal for transposempi
```

When I remove the -C option the compiling passes but the result still the same.

```
/mpif90 -g -O0 -Minfo transposeMVA.cuf       pgfortran-Info-Switch -Mvect -fast forces -O2
transposempi:
    140, Generated vector sse code for the loop
    146, Loop not vectorized: may not be beneficial
         Unrolled inner loop 8 times
    157, Memory copy idiom, loop replaced by call to __c_mcopy4
    178, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
    190, CUDA kernel generated
        190, !$cuf kernel do <<< (*,*), (128,1) >>>
    217, all reduction inlined
```

I will appreciate any help.

```
module transpose_m

  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: cudaTileDim = 32
  integer, parameter :: blockRows = 8

contains

  attributes(global) &
       subroutine cudaTranspose(odata, ldo, idata, ldi)
    real, intent(out) :: odata(ldo,*)
    real, intent(in) :: idata(ldi,*)
    integer, value, intent(in) :: ldo, ldi
    real, shared :: tile(cudaTileDim+1, cudaTileDim)
    integer :: x, y, j

    x = (blockIdx%x-1) * cudaTileDim + threadIdx%x
    y = (blockIdx%y-1) * cudaTileDim + threadIdx%y

    do j = 0, cudaTileDim-1, blockRows
       tile(threadIdx%x, threadIdx%y+j) = idata(x,y+j)
    end do

    call syncthreads()

    x = (blockIdx%y-1) * cudaTileDim + threadIdx%x
    y = (blockIdx%x-1) * cudaTileDim + threadIdx%y

    do j = 0, cudaTileDim-1, blockRows
       odata(x,y+j) = tile(threadIdx%y+j, threadIdx%x)          
    end do
  end subroutine cudaTranspose

end module transpose_m

!
! Main code
!

program transposeMPI
  use cudafor
  use mpi
  use transpose_m 

  implicit none

  ! global array size
  integer, parameter :: nx = 2048, ny = 2048

  ! host arrays (global)
  real :: h_idata(nx,ny), h_tdata(ny,nx), gold(ny,nx)

  ! CUDA vars and device arrays
  integer :: deviceID
  type (dim3) :: dimGrid, dimBlock
  real, device, allocatable :: &
       d_idata(:,:), d_tdata(:,:), d_sTile(:,:), d_rTile(:,:)

  ! MPI stuff
  integer :: mpiTileDimX, mpiTileDimY
  integer :: myrank, nprocs, tag, ierr, localRank
  integer :: nstages, stage, sRank, rRank
  integer :: status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  real(8) :: timeStart, timeStop
  character (len=10) :: localRankStr

  integer :: i, j, nyl, jl, jg, p
  integer :: xOffset, yOffset

  ! for MVAPICH set device before MPI initialization

  call get_environment_variable('MV2_COMM_WORLD_LOCAL_RANK', &
       localRankStr)
  read(localRankStr,'(i10)') localRank
  ierr = cudaSetDevice(localRank)

  ! MPI initialization

  call MPI_init(ierr)
  call MPI_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank, ierr)
  call MPI_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nProcs, ierr)

  ! check parameters and calculate execution configuration

  if (mod(nx,nProcs) == 0 .and. mod(ny,nProcs) == 0) then
     mpiTileDimX = nx/nProcs
     mpiTileDimY = ny/nProcs
  else
     write(*,*) 'ny must be an integral multiple of nProcs'
     call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
     stop
  endif

  if (mod(mpiTileDimX, cudaTileDim) /= 0 .or. &
       mod(mpiTileDimY, cudaTileDim) /= 0) then
     write(*,*) 'mpiTileDimX and mpitileDimY must be an ', &
          'integral multiple of cudaTileDim'
     call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
     stop
  end if

  if (mod(cudaTileDim, blockRows) /= 0) then
     write(*,*) 'cudaTileDim must be a multiple of blockRows'
     call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
     stop
  end if

  dimGrid = dim3(mpiTileDimX/cudaTileDim, &
       mpiTileDimY/cudaTileDim, 1)
  dimBlock = dim3(cudaTileDim, blockRows, 1)

  ! write parameters

  if (myrank == 0) then
     write(*,*)
     write(*,"(/,'Array size: ', i0,'x',i0,/)") nx, ny

     write(*,"('CUDA block size: ', i0,'x',i0, &
          ',  CUDA tile size: ', i0,'x',i0)") &
          cudaTileDim, blockRows, cudaTileDim, cudaTileDim

     write(*,"('dimGrid: ', i0,'x',i0,'x',i0, &
          ',   dimBlock: ', i0,'x',i0,'x',i0,/)") &
          dimGrid%x, dimGrid%y, dimGrid%z, &
          dimBlock%x, dimBlock%y, dimBlock%z

     write(*,"('nprocs: ', i0, ',  Local input array size: ', &
          i0,'x',i0)") nprocs, nx, mpiTileDimY
     write(*,"('mpiTileDim: ', i0,'x',i0,/)") &
          mpiTileDimX, mpiTileDimY
  endif

  ! initialize data

  ! host - each process has entire array on host (for now)

  do p = 0, nProcs-1
     do jl = 1, mpiTileDimY
        jg = p*mpiTileDimY + jl
        do i = 1, nx
           h_idata(i,jg) = i+(jg-1)*nx 
        enddo
     enddo
  enddo

  gold = transpose(h_idata)

  ! device - each process has 
  ! nx*mpiTileDimY = ny*mpiTileDimX  elements

  allocate(d_idata(nx, mpiTileDimY), &
       d_tdata(ny, mpiTileDimX), &
       d_sTile(mpiTileDimX,mpiTileDimY), &
       d_rTile(mpiTileDimX, mpiTileDimY))

  yOffset = myrank*mpiTileDimY
  d_idata(1:nx,1:mpiTileDimY) = &
       h_idata(1:nx,yOffset+1:yOffset+mpiTileDimY)

  d_tdata = -1.0


  ! ---------
  ! transpose
  ! ---------

  call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  timeStart = MPI_Wtime()

  ! 0th stage - local transpose

  call cudaTranspose<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>> &
       (d_tdata(myrank*mpiTileDimY+1,1), ny, &
       d_idata(myrank*mpiTileDimX+1,1), nx)

  ! other stages that involve MPI transfers

  do stage = 1, nProcs-1
     ! sRank = the rank to which myrank sends data
     ! rRank = the rank from which myrank receives data
     sRank = modulo(myrank-stage, nProcs) 
     rRank = modulo(myrank+stage, nProcs) 

     call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

     ! pack tile so data to be sent is contiguous

     !$cuf kernel do(2) <<<*,*>>>
     do j = 1, mpiTileDimY
        do i = 1, mpiTileDimX
           d_sTile(i,j) = d_idata(sRank*mpiTileDimX+i,j)
        enddo
     enddo

     call MPI_SENDRECV(d_sTile, mpiTileDimX*mpiTileDimY, &
          MPI_REAL, sRank, myrank, &
          d_rTile, mpiTileDimX*mpiTileDimY, MPI_REAL, &
          rRank, rRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)

     ! do transpose from receive tile into final array 
     ! (no need to unpack)

     call cudaTranspose<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>> &
          (d_tdata(rRank*mpiTileDimY+1,1), ny, &
          d_rTile, mpiTileDimX)

  end do ! stage     

  call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  timeStop = MPI_Wtime()

  ! check results

  h_tdata = d_tdata

  xOffset = myrank*mpiTileDimX
  if (all(h_tdata(1:ny,1:mpiTileDimX) == &
       gold(1:ny, xOffset+1:xOffset+mpiTileDimX))) then
     if (myrank == 0) then
        write(*,"('Bandwidth (GB/s): ', f7.2,/)") &
             2.*(nx*ny*4)/(1.0e+9*(timeStop-timeStart)) 
     endif
  else
     write(*,"('[',i0,']', *** Failed ***,/)") myrank
  endif

  ! cleanup

  deallocate(d_idata, d_tdata, d_sTile, d_rTile)

  call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program transposeMPI
```

Comment: Did you compile with any debugging options? Did you try a debugger?

Comment: I did not add debug option

Comment: Try compiling with `-C -g -O0 -traceback`, re-run and post the output.

Comment: Edited based on your comments. Thanks

Comment: It's good practice with a segfault to identify the actual line of code that is producing the segfault.  My guess is that your MVAPICH build does not have proper GPU support compiled in.  Without it, this is illegal: `call MPI_SENDRECV(d_sTile, ...`.  Unless your MPI has GPU support, you cannot pass a GPU device pointer to an MPI function.  Doing so will cause a segfault.   To help confirm this, you could first confirm that this line is indeed causing the segfault, and then work around it (as a test) by performing D2H and H2D copies around the MPI_SENDRECV, and have MPI work with a host buffer.

Comment: Robert Crovella, you are a rock star! But I will need to get the right MVAPICH to my system, otherwise lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The follwing works. Thanks Robert

```
    h_sTile = d_sTile

    call MPI_SENDRECV(h_sTile, mpiTileDimX*mpiTileDimY, &
    MPI_REAL, sRank, myrank, &
    h_rTile, mpiTileDimX*mpiTileDimY, MPI_REAL, &
    rRank, rRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)

   !data to device device buffer 
   d_rTile = h_rTile
```

I need to get the right MVAPICH.

Thanks for your help